# I keep hearing that all the branches are SO different. Would branching off be feasible?

Tags: discussion, denominations

I always try asking questions without denomination specification. I end up being told how the different branches would have different answers, thus making it too broad. Would splitting religions of Christianity be too problematic?

Comment: How would this help people in your situation? You would still have to post your questions under the branch from which you were interested in getting answers. You still couldn't post broad questions that cross all of those boundaries. You would still need to put some effort into determining the scope of your questions. How would having separate sites instead of separate tags help you any?

Comment: Consider: [I'm not clear exactly how "overview" questions work](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3795)

Answer (score 3):

## Would splitting religions of Christianity be too problematic?

Yes. It would be too problematic. For many reasons.

1. How would you define which group(s) belong on which site?
2. How would you handle questions that apply to multiple groups?
3. How would you handle small groups, that don't have a critical mass to have their own site (which, in reality, would probably be every single one--Catholicism being a possible exception).

More to the point, as @Caleb mentioned in comments, this wouldn't actually address your problem at all, any way.

You would *still* need to scope your question exactly the same way. The only difference is you'd put it on a different site, rather than using different tags.

So in this case, splitting the site is a solution looking for a problem.